# Question regarding differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a question on differentiation.

Suppose we have $y=f(x)$.

Is ${dy\over dx}={1 \over {dx \over dy}}$?

I know we can find some counterexamples to it, like in polar coordinates:

$$x=r\cos(\theta),\ y=r\sin(\theta)$$
$${\partial x\over \partial r}=\cos(\theta)={\partial r\over \partial x}$$

This part comes from the Laplace equation in PDE:

Given the following equation:

$\Delta u=0,\ u=u(x,y)$
$Change\ x=r\cos(\theta),\ y=r\sin(\theta)$

The Jacobian of the transformation is

$$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
{\partial x \over \partial r} & {\partial y \over \partial r}\\
{\partial x \over \partial \theta} & {\partial y \over \partial \theta}\end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
{\cos(\theta)} & {\sin(\theta)}\\
{-r\sin(\theta)} & {r\cos(\theta)}\end{array} \right)$$

The inverse matrix is

$$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
{\partial r \over \partial x} & {\partial \theta \over \partial x}\\
{\partial r \over \partial y} & {\partial \theta \over \partial y}\end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
{\cos(\theta)} & {-\sin(\theta)\over r}\\
{\sin(\theta)} & {cos(\theta)\over r}\end{array} \right)$$

This portion comes from the book "Partial Differential Equations, an Introduction" by Walter Strauss. He also gives a warning that ${\partial r \over \partial x}\not=({\partial x \over \partial r})^{-1}$. 
I will like to know, under what circumstances can ${dy\over dx}={1 \over {dx \over dy}}$?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dx}=(\frac{dx}{dy})^{-1}$ is true, your "counter example" is wrong. It should be $\frac{dr}{dx} = 1/\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: What you wrote doesn't make sense. First, you mention function of one variable, and then provide a function of two variables as a counterexample, and do it wrong anyway.

Comment: Hi. Initially I thought I might have made a mistake somewhere. However, I was attempting a question in PDE about Laplace equation: $\Delta u=0$, where $u=u(x,y)$. I shall edit my post to make it clearer.:)

Comment: I have posted some details where I am confused in. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: @Dan: No, it is correct: $\partial r / \partial x = (\partial/\partial x)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=(r\cos\theta)/r=\cos\theta$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I will like to know, under what circumstances can $\frac{dy}{dx}=\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^{-1}$?

These are just thoughts around that question: they're too lengthy for comments, but just minor observations.

Suppose you have $u = f(x, y)$, $v = g(x, y)$. Suppose you take point $(x_0, y_0)$ and its' image is $(u_0, v_0)$. Also, let there exist inverse differentiable functions $x = \tilde{f} (u, v)$, $y = \tilde{g}(u, v)$. Ok, you want $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \left ( \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \right )^{-1}$. We always have an equality for Jacobi matrices: $$\frac{D(u, v)}{D(x, y)}\bigg \vert_{(x_0. y_0)} \frac{D(x, y)}{D(u, v)} \bigg \vert_{(u_0. v_0)} = I $$

What will this imply for a partial derivatives of Jacobi matrices? We'll just check the result of Jacobian mulitplication and compare it with $I$ matrix at right side.
So, the element ${I}_{1, 1} = 1$: since $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = 1$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} = 1$, you have that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = 0$, which means that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 0 $ or $\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = 0$. Let's consider the case $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 0 $; this leads to $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} = 0$ for ${I}_{1, 2}=0$ and that means $\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} = 0$ (since Jacobi matrices must have full rank). Checking $I_{2,2} = 1$ implies $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}  = 1$. So, you see what necessary conditions appear? They are not very interesting: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x_0, y_0) = 0 $ or $\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}(u_0, v_0) = 0$ is necessary and sufficient to have 
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} (x_0, y_0) \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} (u_0, v_0) = 1$ and 
$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(x_0, y_0) \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} (u_0, v_0)  = 1$.
Something more interesting happens when you want this to be true for all points on plane. This will lead to maps like $u = f(x), \; v = g(x, y)$ (if only one of derivatives $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ or $\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$ vanishes everywhere) or like $u = f(x), \; v = g(y)$ (if both derivatives vanish everywhere). The latter case is kind of obvious.

Answer (score 1):

It is true if you are dealing with a function of one variable $y = f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have this feeling too. Can you look at my updated post to comment why we cannot do that for the example that I have just recently added to this post. Thank you.:)

Comment: I think I know where the error is: For functions of single variables most of the time we can do the reciprocal,except at those points that the derivative is 0. For multivariable cases, we cannot simply just invert the derivative. If we write $r=\sqrt(x^2+y^2)$ and take the derivative, we will obtain ${\partial r \over \partial x}=\cos(\theta)$