# Why $\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} \ne\frac{1}{\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}} $?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In case of an implicit function $f(x,y)=0$, $ \frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}}$ ,  but if $f(x,y)=0 $ such that $ x=g(r,\theta) $ and $y=h(r,\theta)$ then why   $\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} \ne\frac{1}{\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}} $ ?

I am a beginner and found it intriguing while converting the coordinates in my mechanical engineering course.

Comment: Related (maybe duplicate?): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530733/question-regarding-differentiation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compute $\partial x/\partial r$, it's understood that you're supposed to keep $\theta$ constant, but when you compute $\partial r/\partial y$, you're supposed to keep $x$ constant, which is something completely different. In view of this, there shouldn't be any reason to expect that $\partial x/\partial r = 1/(\partial r/\partial x)$.

What *is* true, however, is that the Jacobian matrices are each other's inverses:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\partial x/\partial r & \partial x/\partial \theta
\\
\partial y/\partial r & \partial y/\partial \theta
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\partial r/\partial x & \partial r/\partial y
\\
\partial \theta/\partial x & \partial \theta/\partial y
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
.
$$